# Unknown error num `5508328` of emscripten compiled wasm

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I have a C++ project, and I want to compile it to WASM and use it in js. This project will be compiled and get a cli used this way:

`./CLI -m model_file_path -f format -output_dir ./`

First step, I just compile this CMake project with:

```
emcmake cmake ..
```

And I get the `CLI.js` and `CLI.wasm`， run directly in Node:

`node CLI.js -m model_file_path -f format -output_dir ./`

It did get the same result with C++ Cli.

So I compile it again, but with `modularize` :

And I use it in JS, I first write the file selected in front end web to emscrpten virtual file system:

```
        // uint8_arrs[0] are byte arrays converted from `inputModelFile.raw`, choosed by user.
        module['FS'].writeFile('./original_model', uint8_arrs[0]);
```

And then I combine the args to `args = ["-m", "./original_model", ...]`, call the main entrance:

```
module.callMain(args)
```

But I get weird error in catch:

```
try{
module.callMain(args)
}catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        success = false;
        ret = e;
    }
```

Error:

[image: err here]

What's the `5508328` mean? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

`args` has an option `-l` and I just push an integer. Should use its string.

`number.toString()`